# Move project into a solution (sub)folder (using premake5/VisualStudio2017)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, premake

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and the premake 5 programs.
To generate my projects I have my workspace in my premake5.lua file.

Becose my project is referencing other projects from older solutions, I can just include those basicaly with there own premake5.lua file to generate that specific project, for example shown [here](https://github.com/LovelySanta/glfw/blob/master/premake5.lua). As you can see, the whole source code and premake5.lua is in included as a github submodule into my current solution, so I cannot change that premake5.lua file.

The solutions premake5.lua file looks like:

```
workspace WorkSpaceName
    ...

-- glfw project
include "git submodule premake5.lua filename"

-- main project
project MainProjectName
    links
    {
        "GLFW",
        ...
    }
    ...
```

As of now, inside VisualStudio I got a file structure like

```
Solution
    - Main project (with premake5.lua file)
    - glfw project (github submodule, with own premake5.lua)
    - ...          (other projects in solution)
```

**My question:** Can I move the project glfw inside a solution subfolder from inside the premake5.lua file in the main project without touching the file from the git submodule? Then my file structure would look like:

```
Solution
    - Main project (with premake5.lua file)
    - <FolderName>
        - glfw project (github submodule, with own premake5.lua)
        - ... (other projects in solution/<FolderName>)
    - ...     (other projects in solution)
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own solution afther 2 long hours of searching:

By adding the projects to a group, they appear in a virtual folder.

```
group "Dependecies"
    include "git submodule premake5.lua filename"
group "" -- end of "Dependensies"
```